# Extracting multiple columns across matricies to a new matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple CSV files that contain data structured as follows:

```
A,B,C,D,
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8,
9,10,11,12,
```

that were generated using Monte Carlo methods. In order to do some statistical analysis on the data, I need to all of the data from the same column in each file,in a single matrix (i.e., all the data from column `A` in multiple files in one matrix). I know how to do this by brute forcing things with loops, but is there an easier way to do this in R than that?

Sample data:

```
A <- c(1,5,9)
B <- c(2,6,10)
C <- c(3,7,11)
D <- c(4,8,12) 
data <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend storing data from all CSV files in a `list`; then you can use `sapply` to extract relevant columns and store resulting columns in a `matrix`:

```
# Sample data
df <- read.csv(text =
    "A,B,C,D,
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8,
9,10,11,12,", header = T)

# Store data in a list
lst <- list(df, df);

# Extract column A and store as matrix by `cbind`ing entries
cbind(sapply(lst, function(x) x$A))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    5    5
#[3,]    9    9
```

---

Or to do this for columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` in one go:

```
lapply(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), function(s)
    cbind.data.frame(sapply(lst, function(x) x[s])))
#[[1]]
#  A A
#1 1 1
#2 5 5
#3 9 9
#
#[[2]]
#   B  B
#1  2  2
#2  6  6
#3 10 10
#
#[[3]]
#   C  C
#1  3  3
#2  7  7
#3 11 11
#
#[[4]]
#   D  D
#1  4  4
#2  8  8
#3 12 12
```